# Problems importing a DLL in c#

Tags: c#, dll

I'm having hard times importing a C# Dll into another simple test application (console, winform, you name it).

Basically it consist in a huge library which consumes the European Community Vat checking service (which URL I believe is [Vat webservice](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl).

The service makes you download a library, then the implementation of the code is up to you.

What I did is starting a new C# class library in Visual studio 2010 and then adding [this class](http://pastebin.com/KwBxPZPa) which is automatically downloaded from the webservice for your own use, and then wrote this snippet I found in the web.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;


namespace EuroVAT
{
    public class EuroVAT
    {
        public static Array check(string country, string vatNum)
        {
            bool valid;
            string name;
            string address;
            checkVatService vatchecker = new checkVatService();
            vatchecker.checkVat(ref country, ref vatNum, out valid, out name, out address);

            return new object[] {country,
                                 vatNum,
                                 valid,
                                 name,
                                 address
                                 };
        }
    }
}
```

Well, when I create a new Console application, then add a reference (right click on project name, add reference, browse to the dll) to my DLL compiled from a Class Library project which included the 2 classes I linked/quoted up here.

Here's some code I tried to use my dll:

```
using EuroVAT;

namespace DLLTEST
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            EuroVat test = new EuroVat();


        }
    }
}
```

Basically I am not able to call them from the program. All I get when I try to call EuroVAT object is

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'EuroVAT' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to build, close, reopen project. Tried to put it in Winforms and so on to no avail.
I always get that error.

What am I doing wrong?
What can I do to solve it?

One more question:

What exactly this code is doing?

```
    return new object[] {country,
                         vatNum,
                         valid,
                         name,
                         address
                         };
```

It's like returning an array of objects?
Because when I run the program all the output is thrown out all togheter. Usually I have to cycle throught the output with some sort of loop...

Last question, if someone can help:

I'll have to include this DLL in a SQL server (2008 I think)

I have read about the subject and discovered that for passing values to SQL Server from a C# dll you have to include various libraries and declare your methods as SqlProcedures, but also passing/retrieving your values as SqlTypes (SqlInt32, SqlString, etc etc).

Here's what I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace WebServiceVatEuropa
{
    class Program
    {
        [SqlProcedure]
        public static Array check(string country, string vatNum)
        {
            bool valid;
            string name;
            string address;
            checkVatService vatchecker = new checkVatService();
            vatchecker.checkVat(ref country, ref vatNum, out valid, out name, out address);

            return new object[] {country,
                                 vatNum,
                                 valid,
                                 name,
                                 address
                                 };
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it's correct.
What I'm missing is how I can cast all those object to SqlTypes like SqlInt32, SqlString and so on. I tried but I got tons of conversion errors and stuff like that. It just won't allow me to declare those objects ad SqlTypes and I can't work out the last to make the last return statement to output those SqlTypes.

Can anyone show an example if possible?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. your class is declared as `EuroVAT`. Whereas you initialize object of type `EuroVat`. Check the register
   Other thing is, try giving your namespace and class different names
2. This:

   ```cs
   return new object[] {country,
                        vatNum,
                        valid,
                        name,
                        address
   };
   ```

   creates an array of `object` type, and populates it with `(object)country`, `(object)vatNum`, `(object)valid`, etc
3. If I get it right how you intend your library to interact with SQL Server, the problem is with this array. Those SQL types, like `SqlInt32`, `SqlString`, `SqlBinary`, etc. do have implicit conversion operators for corresponding types, like `int`, `string`. But since array holds `object` instances, implicit conversion can not be applied. That is the one side. On the other side, SQL Server gets result of `object[]`, and it cannot just handle it. It doesn't know how. I think you should consider using a data acess framework to handle the database, something like plain ADO.NET, or Entity Framework, or whatever. I actually cannot figure out your intentions with these stored procedures you provided.

**EDIT:**

Try passing result to SQL Server through `SqlContext` like this:

```cs
[SqlProcedure]  
public static void UserService(string country, stringvatNum)    
{       
    object[] serverResponse = CheckService(country, vatNum);

    // Variables.       
    SqlMetaData column1Info;        
    SqlDataRecord record;

    // Create the column metadata.      
    column1Info = new
    SqlMetaData("Column1", SqlDbType.Variant);      

    // Create a new record with the column metadata.       
    record = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData[]{column1Info});

     // Mark the begining of the result-set.
     SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(record);

     foreach (var o in serverResponse)      
     {
         record.SetValue(0, o);
         SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(record);        
     }      

     // Mark the end of  the result-set.        
     SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd();  
}

public static object[] CheckService(string country, string vatNum)  
{
     bool valid;        
     string name;       
     string address;        
     checkVatService
     vatchecker = new checkVatService();    
     vatchecker.checkVat(ref country, ref vatNum, out valid, out name, out address);

     return new object[] {country,
                          vatNum,
                          valid,
                          name,
                          address
                         }; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well I managed to use the DLL but it wasn't a uppercase/lowercase problem, but a compilation problem. Solved.

Regarding the object array, I guess I had the right intuition. Thanks.

The SqlTypes hints you gave me are still a bit obscure, so I will wait to mark your answers as solved because I would like to see someone else point of view about this particular subject.

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Edit:

I think I found a way to do the SqlTypes conversion doing like this:

            return new object[] {(SqlString) country,
                                 (SqlString)vatNum,
                                 (SqlBoolean) valid,
                                 (SqlString) name,
                                 (SqlString) address
                                 } ;

But I didn't tested it.

Comment: i thing the problem is that method `check()` can not have return type other than void or int. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx)

Comment: i have updated my previous answer. i hope it will be helpful. But imho, calling web service from inside of sql server... it seems a little bit odd to me.